# how Connect between Binding and Group Detail Page?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, binding, app.xaml

can connect between binding and Group Detail Page ?
Since shortly i create windows 8 application and i have class Data Source But i can't connect between this class and new page ( Group Detail Page).
i'w like control text and image and Subtitle by binding How ?